# Asp.netSendEmail The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: ssl, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I am using google smtp to send email. The Code works correctly in my local Machine. But on Production server i am getting the error message as SendEmail The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at

i have try this, 
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
set it to false but it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for send mail by Google

```
            MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            string FromMailID = "yourgmailid@gmail.com";
            string UserName = "GmailUsername";
            string Password = "GmailPassword";

            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(FromMailID);
            if (FilePath != "")//If attached file otherwise comment
            {
                Attachment PDFfile = new Attachment(FilePath);
                oMail.Attachments.Add(PDFfile);
            }
            oMail.From = fromAddress;
            oMail.To.Add(ToMailID);
            oMail.Subject = Subject;
            oMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            oMail.Body = Mailcontent.ToString();
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";   // We use gmail as our smtp client
            smtpClient.Port = 25;//localhost
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

            smtpClient.Send(oMail);
```

Comment: for The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
check gmail security
login to gmail account from server if remote server